# How to get access to the output buffer with the Web Audio API?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, web-audio-api

I'd like to access the audio data in the output/[destination](http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#AudioContext-section) buffer. To be specific I would like to save the data to a file. I would also like to add custom effects as [AudioNode](http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#AudioNode-section)'s.

How can I achieve this with the Web Audio API? I don't see an AudioDestinationBuffer interface or a way to add a custom [AudioNode](http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#AudioNode-section) in the [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to add one of these http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#JavaScriptAudioNode right before connecting to the destination.

This will give you access to the raw audio data, and any processing made by effect nodes etc. will already be applied. Just make sure this is the very last node before the destination.

Here's a little something on how you use the JavaScriptAudioNode http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/games/#toc-clip-detect, which I hope will illustrate how to access the audio data.

Comment: Also, this node is what you'd use to write those custom effects.

Comment: Thanks Oskar! I already saw your app Plink. Very inspiring :)

Comment: Does anyone know if the JavascriptAudioNode has been deprecated? I don't see it anywhere in the documentation.

Comment: Yepp, it's being replaced by this: https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html#ScriptProcessorNode - I'm not sure about the state of implementation though.

Answer (score 1):

`JavaScriptNode`, later renamed to `ScriptProcessorNode`, has been deprecated in favor of [`AudioWorkletNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioWorkletNode). There is an [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioWorkletProcessor#Examples) on the AudioWorkletProcessor MDN page.